# rails migration using up/down to add and update existing records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I am having to add a 2 new columns to an existing table, those are `created_at`, `updated_at`. However the `created_at` and `updated_at` fields should not be null except there are several existing records in my db so a simple `change` migration is not working. I decided to go with an up/down migration because i needed to update those records first before setting those fields to `not null`.

My migration files looks like so:

```
Class AddColumnsToCharge < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
   def up
     add_column :charges, :created_at, :datetime
     add_column :charges, :updated_at, :datetime
     Charge.update_all(created_at: Time.now, updated_at: Time.now)
   end

  def down
     change_column :charges, :created_at, :datetime, null:false
     change_column :charges, :updated_at, :datetime, null:false
  end
end
```

Now that seems to work because I no longer get errors complaining about existing columns with `created_at`/`updated_at` fields as null values. However my schema.rb does not show those fields as `null: false` instead i see

```
create_table "charges", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.bigint 'amount'
  t.datetime 'created_at'
  t.datetime 'updated_at'
```

what I expected to see was:

```
create_table "charges", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.bigint 'amount'
      t.datetime 'created_at', null: false
      t.datetime 'updated_at', null: false
```

Is my down not being executed or am i doing something wrong in my migration file?(Thanks for any help in advance)

Answer (score 3):

`down` is used when you run `rails db:rollback`, is that what you were trying to do?

`up` is used when running `rails db:migrate`. Usually Rails knows what to do so using `change` is enough in migrations, but sometimes you need do use `up/down` so the migration is reversible.

---

From the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#using-the-up-down-methods)

> You can also use the old style of migration using up and down methods
> instead of the change method. The up method should describe the
> transformation you'd like to make to your schema, and the down method
> of your migration should revert the transformations done by the up
> method. In other words, the database schema should be unchanged if you
> do an up followed by a down. For example, if you create a table in the
> up method, you should drop it in the down method.

Comment: You can also use `reversible do |dir|\ndir.up do\n ...` if most of the migration is suitable for `def change`.

Answer (score 1):

You need this:

```rb
class AddTimestamps < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    reversible do |dir|
      change_table :charges do |t|
        dir.up do
          t.timestamps
          Charge.update_all(created_at: Time.now, updated_at: Time.now)
        end
        dir.down do
          remove_column :charges, :created_at
          remove_column :charges, :updated_at
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The default value of `created_at` and `updated_at` is not reflected in the schema b/c it's always populated by ActiveRecord, they don't have database-configured default values. The value assigned is dynamic, you can only put fixed default values in the schema.

The `null: false` is automatically added (Rails 5 onwards) when you specify `created_at` using the `timestamps` method. The option is not automatically added when you explicitly create/remove the created_at/updated_at columns.

Comment: Sorry maybe i did not explain myself well enough, i did not mean that i expected to see a default date vaule for those fields. what i meant is that i did not see the `not null` constraint reflected in the schema.rb file

Comment: It's not really necessary to have a `not null` constraint in the db, b/c ActiveRecord handles this constraint, not the database.

Comment: Oh I just noticed that Rails 5 does add `null: false` to timestamps. So I guess your expectation that it should be there is correct!

Comment: @juan_code18 I changed my reply to address my misunderstanding of your question and of how ActiveRecord works

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you're looking for something like this.

```
 add_column :charges, :created_at, :datetime
 add_column :charges, :updated_at, :datetime
 change_column_null(:charges, :created_at, false, Time.now)
 change_column_null(:charges, :updated_at, false, Time.now)
```

Check this out [change_column_null](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-change_column_null)

Comment: So this answer doesnt quite work for me because as i said, I currently have conflicting records in my db

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice example of using `up` and `down` (it's from the [Rails Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migration-overview) on migrations:

```rb
class ChangeProductsPrice < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def up
    change_table :products do |t|
      t.change :price, :string
    end
  end

  def down
    change_table :products do |t|
      t.change :price, :integer
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I found a solution that I think works for you as well. I am pretty sure you dont need this but for future people it may be useful. So the idea here is to first add the timestamps but with null possible (null: true), then we update those records with the current Time.zone so they are not null and then we make the null: false for each field. Ill send an exmaple of my code, you should replace the tables with your tabel names

```
class AddTimetableViews < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
 def change
  add_timestamps :table1, null: true
  Table1.where(created_at: nil).update_all(created_at: Time.zone.now, updated_at: Time.zone.now)
  change_column_null :table1, :created_at, false
  change_column_null :table1, :updated_at, false
 end
end
```

This way the current records in your db will be updated and the schema will look like this afterwards:

```
create_table 'table1', force: :cascade do |t|
    ...
    t.datetime 'created_at', null: false
    t.datetime 'updated_at', null: false
end
```

Another shorter way could be

```
class AddTimestampsToTable1AndTable2 < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_timestamps :table1, default: -> { 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' }, null: false
    add_timestamps :table2, default: -> { 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' }, null: false
  end
end
```

This way also works BUT the schema will look a little different, will look like this:

```
create_table 'table1', force: :cascade do |t|
    ...
    t.datetime 'created_at', default: -> { 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' }, null: false
    t.datetime 'updated_at', default: -> { 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' }, null: false
end
```

Hope this works. Any questions happy to ask

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve my issue the long way by running two different migrations.

My first migration added the new columns:

```
Class AddColumnsToCharge < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
   def change
     add_column :charges, :created_at, :datetime
     add_column :charges, :updated_at, :datetime
   end
end
```

Before Running the second migration I went into the rails console and updated the current records: `Charge.update_all(created_at: Time.now, updated_at: Time.now)`

The second migration:

```
Class AddColumnsToCharge < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
     change_column :charges, :created_at, :datetime, null:false
     change_column :charges, :updated_at, :datetime, null:false
  end
end
```

This answer does not answer the initial question but got the job done which is ultimately what i wanted.